# Character spacing in RichEdit control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, controls, richedit

How can I change the character spacing in RichEdit control?

I have tried to use the `CHARFORMAT` structure, but as MSDN says, the `sSpacing` is useless in RichEdit control. Moreover, `SetTextExtra` function is useless in that control's hdc, too.

And I also tried to use the ole interface of that control, the SetSpace function of `ITextFont` interface, ineffective.

Does anybody could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean character spacing between individual characters, I'm not sure if there is anything you can do. If you are talking about spacing between lines, then use the PARAFORMAT structure and the EM_SETPARAFORMAT message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Joe! I mean how to change to the spacing between two characters, not between two lines. For example, the "hello" word, after changed, it will looks like this, "h e l l o". The spacing between letter 'h' and 'e' could be changed with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely works with RichEdit v8.5 in Windows 10.

Be sure you are using the Windows class `"RICHEDIT50W"` (from `MsftEdit.dll`) and not the `"RichEdit20W"` class (from `Riched32.dll`):

```
//Get the ITextDocument interface of the RichEdit control
IUnknown re;
if (SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_GetOleInterface, 0, ref (LPARAM)re) == 0)
   throw new Exception("Could not get ITextDocument from RichEdit");
ITextDocument doc = re as ITextDocument;

//Increase spacing (positive is expanded)
Single spacing = doc.Selection.Font.Spacing;
spacing += 1;
doc.Selection.Font.Spacing = spacing;

//Decrease spacing (negative is compressed)
spacing = doc.Selection.Font.Spacing;
spacing -= 1;
doc.Selection.Font.Spacing = spacing;

//Reset to normal spacing
doc.Selection.Font.Spacing = 0;
```

[image]